# Mongo db update to array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have array object inside my collection. i'm getting extra square bracket when i try to update data into the array object. 
here is the code.

```
    var comments = [{
        'COMMENTED_BY' : employee.SYSTEM_USER_ID,
        'COMMENT' : employee.FIRST_NAME+" "+employee.LAST_NAME+" Started working on this comlaint"
     }];

    if(req.body.complaint.comment){
       comments.push({'COMMENTED_BY' : employee.SYSTEM_USER_ID,'COMMENT': req.body.complaint.comment});
    }   
          Complaint.findByIdAndUpdate(
              req.body.complaint.complaintId,
              {$set: {'STATUS': 1}, $push: {"COMMENTS": comments}},
              {safe: true, upsert: true},
                function(err, model) {
```

My collection looks like below

```
        {
            "COMMENT" : "media delete confirmation UI issue",
            "COMMENTED_BY" : ObjectId("575cc0b39dd420a41d202dad"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("575fe9e1a5ee92201b58011e"),
            "CREATED_AT" : ISODate("2016-06-14T11:26:25.003Z")
        }, 
        {
            "COMMENT" : "Could someone explain to me how Luke Ronchi gets in when Tom Latham is a very capable keeper as well as batsman? Why not another specialist batsman/bowler?",
            "COMMENTED_BY" : ObjectId("575cc0b39dd420a41d202dad"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("575fea19a5ee92201b58011f"),
            "CREATED_AT" : ISODate("2016-06-14T11:27:21.136Z")
        },
        [
          {
           "COMMENT" : "media delete confirmation UI issue",
           "COMMENTED_BY" : ObjectId("575cc0b39dd420a41d202dad"),
           "_id" : ObjectId("575fe9e1a5ee92201b58011e"),
           "CREATED_AT" : ISODate("2016-06-14T11:26:25.003Z")
          }, 
          {
          "COMMENT" : "Could someone explain to me how Luke Ronchi gets in when Tom Latham is a very capable keeper as well as batsman? Why not another specialist batsman/bowler?",
           "COMMENTED_BY" : ObjectId("575cc0b39dd420a41d202dad"),
           "_id" : ObjectId("575fea19a5ee92201b58011f"),
           "CREATED_AT" : ISODate("2016-06-14T11:27:21.136Z")
          }
        ]
```

i want to remove the extra [] brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because, you are just pushing array of objects, `comment`, into `COMMENTS` array field while updating. Use `$each` instead, while pushing array of objects.

See [doc-$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) for more info.

Try the following query. :-

```
 Complaint.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.body.complaint.complaintId,
          {$set: {'STATUS': 1}, $push: {"COMMENTS":{$each : comments}},
          {safe: true, upsert: true})
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much!